# Adding item to a sharepoint list using rest api

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a list having columns naming - Column1,Column2,Column3..etc.
Items are added to the list using rest api. 
Can the data to these fields be set using a loop. ?It need it to be set dynamically depending upon a number from user- so require a loop. How will the code be..

My current code is below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle(listname)/Items", 
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    data:  __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.customlistListItem' },
                        Title: 'title',
                        Column1:'value1',
                        Column2:'value2',
                        Column3:'value3',
                        Column4:'value4',
                        Column5:'value5',
    success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        alert('added');



    },
    error: function (error) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        alert('Some error occured. Please try again later.');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. But I was able to solve this.
Created an object - creating attributes and setting its value dynamically, and passed this object to function.